# swift animateKeyframes withRelativeStartTime not working

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I want to achieve an animate: Each cell rightImage move first, and after rightImage moved, the backgroundImage(which is a gif) start to animating. However, the moving animation and gif startAnimating always start at the same time. Like the demo below:
[image]

Here is Debug Log which print moving timestamp and animating timestamp:

```
<<< start index:  0
>>> start transfrom 2023-04-04 10:32:39
>>> start animating 2023-04-04 10:32:39
<<< start index:  1
>>> start transfrom 2023-04-04 10:32:43
>>> start animating 2023-04-04 10:32:43
<<< start index:  2
>>> start transfrom 2023-04-04 10:32:47
>>> start animating 2023-04-04 10:32:47
```

Here is my animation code:

```
func startMoving() {
        let duration: Double = 4
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeLinear], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.7/duration, animations: {
                print(">>> start transfrom")
                self.frontImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -20, y: 0)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.7/duration, relativeDuration: 1.5/duration, animations: {
                print(">>> start animating")
                self.backgroundImageView.startAnimating()
            })
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.backgroundImageView.stopAnimating()
        })
    }
```

Comment: instead of ```calculationModeLinear``` try using ```calculationModeDiscrete```

Comment: this dose not help, I tried and I believed that the option can only control the speed of animation.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but your relativeDuration values don't add up to 1.0. They are supposed to. Also, why are you trying to animate a gif? Why don't you just delay animating the gif until the other animations are complete?

Comment: the reason to control the gif is that I want to control it play in a certain seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things...

1 - you are using relative start time and relative duration incorrectly

2 - keyframe animation don't work the way you think they do

The relative times are a **percentage** of the duration.

If you want the first keyframe to start immediately, and run for 70% of the total duration, it should look like this:

```
UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
```

and you want the second keyframe to start when the first animation ends (so, 70% from the start), and run for the remainder:

```
UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.7, relativeDuration: 0.3, animations: {
```

So, let's changing the timing parameters, and add a couple more `print()` statements:

```
func startMoving() {
    let duration: Double = 4
    
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeLinear], animations: {
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            print(">>> start transfrom")
            self.frontImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -20, y: 0)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.7, relativeDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            print(">>> start animating")
            self.backgroundImageView.startAnimating()
        })
        
    }, completion: { _ in
        print(">>> completion")
        self.backgroundImageView.stopAnimating()
    })
    
    print(">>> end of startMoving()")
}
```

What you'll see in the debug console is ***immediately***:

```
>>> start transfrom
>>> start animating
>>> end of startMoving()
```

and at the end of 4-seconds:

```
>>> completion
```

However, you'll still see the animation begin at Zero.

Keyframe animation does ***not*** wait to execute code. Inside the `UIView.animateKeyframes` block, UIKit analyzes all of the `addKeyFrame` segments *immediately*, and then "plays the animation."

That's why the resulting animation will look different depending on the `KeyFrameAnimationOptions` (`.calulationMode...` values).

Logically, we **think** that this line: `self.backgroundImageView.startAnimating()` will ***execute at 70% of the total duration.*** In reality, it executes when UIKit builds the animation, which is why your image view animation begins at the start.

If you want the "front" view to slide over, and ***then*** start the image view animation, you need to play the slide-over animation and start the image view animation when that has completed.

Something along these lines:

```
func startMoving() {
    let duration: Double = 4.0 * 0.7
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        print(">>> start transfrom")
        self.frontImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -20, y: 0)
    }, completion: { _ in
        print(">>> start animating")
        // maybe set imageView animation properties...
        self.backgroundImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        self.backgroundImageView.animationDuration = 1.0    // 1-second to cycle through all images
        self.backgroundImageView.startAnimating()
    })
    
    print(">>> end of startMoving()")
}
```

Comment: Yes, I put it in frontImage's completion block and it works. Thanks, I have noticed the UIKIt will execute code immediately. This answer is right! Thanks again.